# How to select an id in bs4 which is a number?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't select using id in bs4(BeautiFullSoup) because the id is a number.

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautiFullSoup("<td id='1'>This is text</td>", 'lxml')
td = soup.select('#1')
```

Which is showing this error

```
    raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed id selector at position 0
  line 1:
#1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. use `bs4.BeautifulSoup` instead of `bs4.BeautiFullSoup`

```
td = soup.find(attrs={'id': '1'})
```

You can also select parent element of td then use for loop to get desire output.

Answer (score 0):

its not only because of that, beautifulsoup is also written wrong, and it generally looks like some key parts are missing, if you arent very experienced with that code yet, id suggest to use pycharm, since those errors are easy fixed.